# d3.js, sankey and bootstrap: change all colors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I'm using d3.js and sankey in my application. I created a simple HTML file with the sankey and the result is the follow (exactly what I expect):

[image]

I did a quick cut and paste in the application in ASP.NET Core with Bootstrap and the result is this one:

[image]

I think in some ways Bootstrap is changing sankey. Do you have any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Add `fill: none` to all your paths first, that should remove the black lines

Comment: yes, thank you. it removes the black line but the lines are still dark, like the opacity is ignored

Comment: Did you maybe just forget to copy a CSS file? Try `fill-opacity: 0.3`